# Export list issue - 2013 SharePoint Foundation & Office 2016

Tags: 2013, office-365, excel, office-2016

We have a E3 Office subscription. We moved to Office 365 and still have an on prem 2013 Foundation Sharepoint farm. However when a user with O365 goes to SharePoint 2013 and exports a list to excel they get prompted for credentials, once signed in, it gives them the error:
 **"Cannot connect to the server at this time. Changes to your data cannot be saved"**

Exporting work fine with office 2013.

I have added the site to the trusted sites. Removed **Security feature Check for publisher's certificate revocation.**

Looking for other suggestions.

Comment: hi check https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2d7fd6a-c5fc-4104-a582-dad6350bbbf1/cannot-connect-to-the-server-at-this-time-changes-to-your-data-cannot-be-saved?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fix-problems-opening-documents-in-SharePoint-libraries-31329fa1-4ad0-47fc-95d8-bb0c5b12a536

Comment: http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/excel-cannot-connect-to-the-sharepoint-list-436.aspx

Comment: I tried the last article already. The other two I don't think apply to my question as all documents and excel files open properly.  It only happens on exporting list to excel files.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error and I resolved it by removing all credentials in Credential Manager.  To access Credential Manager
1. Go to Control Panel
2. Click on Credential Manager

[image: Credential Manager]

Comment: Could you please add some more details around how to remove the credentials from the Credential Manager? It will make your answer more useful